# My server cant make a connection to the outside

Tags: networking, server, dns, resolv.conf

I am running a newly installed Ubuntu Server 20.04. Every time I try to access the internet or download something I get this screen.

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

I have tried to switch my DNS and it still gives me this error. The router that it's connected to is working fine when I connect anything else to it, just the server is not.

Comment: Did you intend to link to a screenshot of the `nano` text editor? is that **really** what you see when you try to access the internet? Can you give some examples of actual commands you are using to access / download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a bad iso -_- . I just reflash it now its works. thanks for all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

so apparetnly it cannot resolve the DNS address. I would recommend trying to set the dns address to 8.8.8.8 which is google's dns address. You can do that by typing the following. Make sure to change the System eth0 to your connections name. You can check the name of your connection my running the first command.

```
nmcli con show

nmcli conn modify "System eth0" ipv4.dns  "8.8.8.8 8.8.8.4"
```

Comment: nmcil is not installed

Comment: are you on Red Hat distribution or Debian?

Comment: ubuntu server 20.04

Comment: sudo apt-get install network-manager

Comment: I cant it won't let me connect to the outside

Comment: oh I thought it would just download it from your cached packages, in that case try sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml and then once in there under nameservers change the address to 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4